# Why is voltage subtracted in this 2-resistor circuit to find the current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current

I am figuring out the current for the following circuit:

[image: Circuit]

Using `V = IR`, I would expect to do `I = V / R` and then do:

I = (20 + 50) / (1 + 2) = 70 / 3 Amps.

However, the actual current is:

(20 - 50) / 3 = -10 Amps

Why are the voltages subtracted rather than added?

References to blog posts / textbook chapters would also be appreciated (if available).

Here's the full solution, if it helps anyone:

[image]

Comment: Are the voltages series aiding or series opposing?

Comment: @Andyaka, I'm not sure. I guess it isn't specified? I'm using Schaum's Outline of Electric Circuits, so maybe there's some convention in that textbook.

Comment: @Andyaka, I've added the full solution to the post -- if that gives additional context.

Comment: The voltages **are** added. However, in going round the loop in a consistent direction, one voltage has the opposite polarity to the other. What's (+50) + (-20)?

Comment: @Andyaka, ok I think I've figured it out.

The voltages are series opposing since the (+) signs are facing each other. 50 - 20 = 30 V. V = I / R = 30 / 3 = 10. However, the sign is negative since it's asking us to find the current flowing clockwise, but in reality the current is flowing counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try to analyze this equivalent circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKqxN4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see from node A to B we have a voltage rise by 20V and from B to node C we have a voltage drop by 50V. Therefore V_CA = +20 - 50V = - 30V.